# Background-Size: auto not working as expected on android 6

Tags: android, html, css, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm making some little zoom-overlay components for a website, and so far I'd tested on iOS, IE, Chrome, Safari, Android 7.0.1 Chrome, without issue.

However I tested on my old phone (android 6) and it is not behaving at all as expected. It appears the root issue is that `background-size: auto` is not actually rendering at the original size (images are 4k, so they should appear quite zoomed in on a 1080p screen) they appear only slightly larger than when contained in the page.

Does anyone know why `background-size: auto` would not be showing my images at their true sizes? thank you.

**Edit:** I think my images are hitting a size limit and being auto-downscaled, which background-size is treating as their true size, while using an image element avoids this, likely due to automatic handling of original size values. If this is the case, does anyone know the actual limits?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `background-size: auto` then in default it will take the full width image as background image